# SPARQL over custom representation of semantic data

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web

I have a non-standard way of storing and representing semantic data, and I was looking into some possibilities of supporting SPARQL queries. It seems that the best solution is to implement a so-called *driver* of a standard API framework, such as Apache Jena, but at least for Jena it's not so clear how can this be done. The following image taken from the official documentation suggests that I should implement the *Store API*, however I couldn't find documentation concerning this. Furthermore, the [Java docs of TDB](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/tdb/), Jena's native triple store, implies that there is no Store API.

[image]

A secondary question is whether there is a Python alternative to Jena (which is written in Java)?

Comment: what is a "driver" in this context? and which format are you talking about?

Comment: A "driver" in this context means something similar to a JDBC driver - a software component enabling the interaction with a database that stores the data. As for the data format, it stores the individuals separately from the classes, and therefore out-of-the-box solutions are incompatible.

Comment: So, you're talking about relational databases? There has been SDB, true, but it's afaik not maintained anymore. There are other RDB to RDF approaches like R2RML, you just have to use a tool that supports R2RML.

Comment: RDF toolkit in Python: https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib

Comment: The interface you want is DatasetGraph and there are various classes providing implementation framework to lessen the total work. See also package org.apache.jena.dboe.storage.

Comment: Thanks. RDFLib seems to be the easiest approach for me.

Comment: But RDFLib is just for standard RDF data, not for what you called before when you said *"have a non-standard way of storing and representing semantic data"*

Comment: I can override the [Store interface](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.store.Store) to accommodate my data format (more info [here](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/persistence.html)). It's easier for me than Jena because my code is also in Python and the Store interface seems to have better documentation than that of DatasetGraph of Jena.

Comment: As for R2RML, I agree it's neat in its approach, however the data sources it supports are limited for my use case, and therefore I would have to implement a customized connector between my data source to the RML processor which might be not worthwhile.